# Finding sum of all binary expansions of numbers from 1 to n

Tags: c++, binary

Recently, I came across a question posted as a challenge at a competitive site. There it was asked to find the sum of all the decimal interpretation of binary representations of numbers from 1 to n. Suppose when n = 4, so, sum will be 1 + 10 + 11 + 100 = 122. Since this number could be very large so answer should be modulo 1000000007.
I came across the following solutions but was not able to optimize it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
int Mod(string s, int a)
{
    int res = 0, i, l = s.size();
    for( i = 0 ; i < l ; i++ )
    {
        res = ( res * 10 + s[i] - '0' ) % a;
    }
    return res;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        long long n;
        cin >> n;
        int Sum = 0, mod = 1000000007;
        queue<string> q;
        q.push("1");
        while( n > 0 )
        {
            n--;
            string s1 = q.front();
            q.pop();
            Sum = ( Sum + Mod(s1, mod) ) % mod;
            string s2 = s1;
            q.push(s1.append("0"));
            q.push(s2.append("1"));
        }
        cout << Sum << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Constraints:
1 <= t <= 10^5, 1 <= n <= 10^18, Allowed Time = 1 sec. Any optimization help would be admirable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to optimize? runtime? memory usage? readable code?

Comment: I forgot to mention the time limit. I have edited it. It is 1 sec. So, obviously its the runtime.

Comment: `There it was asked to find the sum of all the binary representations of numbers from 1 to n.` I don't quite get the idea - there should be only one binary representation for each number on one platform. Do you mean the sum of bits used in the binary representation?

Comment: No, @SimonKraemer, actually its the sum of all the numbers  formed by binary representations of numbers from 1 to n. Suppose when n = 4, so, sum will be 1 + 10 + 11 + 100 = 122.

Comment: @Shashank Actually, this is is the sum of the *decimal interpretation* of the binary representation of the numbers. `10` in your example is not the binary representation of two, it's the decimal representation of ten.

Comment: Yes, @molbdnilo

Comment: Are you trying to read 10^18 into an `int`? That won't work.

Comment: No, @jabaa. I just wrote a working code for few limits. I could change it to long long but it doesn't matter as time complexity will be still high.

Comment: You have a brute force approach. The best idea is to close and forget the code, take a pen and paper and redesign the algorithm. You can't optimize the code.

Comment: Even if you could do one operation per nanosecond, your solution would literally take several decades to finish when n is 10^18. If you look at the patterns of zeros and ones, you can bring this down to a few dozen arithmetic operations rather than billions of billions (and all those memory allocations aren't helping, either).

Comment: @molbdnilo removed that comment, because I misunderstood the task, though its always the same punchline: Do the maths first!

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I did some maths but couldn't derive sufficient conclusion from that.

Comment: then you need to think harder ;). When `n` is eg `15` then there are `15/2` numbers that have the first bit set, `15/4` numbers that have the second bit set.... The trick is just to iterate powers of `2` instead of all numbers from `1` till `N`

Answer (score 0):

After doing some calculative math finally I have come up with the solution. Thanks, to @largest_prime_is_463035818 for providing such hints. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#define mod 1000000007
using namespace std;
long long power(long long x, long long y)
{
    long long res = 1LL;
    while(y)
    {
        if( y & 1LL )
        {
            res = ( res * x ) % mod;
        }
        y >>= 1LL;
        x = ( x * x ) % mod;
    }
    return res;
}
int main()
{
    long long t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        long long n, i, l, m, s = 0;
        cin >> n;
        if( n && (!( n & ( n - 1LL ) )) )
        {
            l = ceil(log2(n)) + 1LL;
        }
        else
        {
            l = ceil(log2(n));
        }
        for( i = 0LL ; i < l ; i++ )
        {
        
            if( n & ( 1LL << i ) )
            {
                m = ( ( ( ( n / ( 1LL << ( i + 1LL ) ) ) * ( 1LL << i ) ) + 1LL ) + ( ( n % ( 1LL << ( i + 1LL ) ) ) % ( 1LL << i ) ) );
            }
            else
            {
                m = ( ( n / ( 1LL << ( i + 1LL ) ) ) * ( 1LL << i ) );
            }
            s = ( s + ( ( ( m % mod ) * power(10, i) ) % mod ) ) % mod;
        }
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```